# MySQL - Perl: How to use an array with IN within a select query? (WHERE IN (@array))

Tags: mysql, arrays, perl

This is an addition to my solved question here:
[how to get array of zip codes within x miles in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144331/mysql-perl-how-to-get-array-of-zip-codes-within-submitted-x-miles-of-submitt)

OK, I have the array @zips. Now I am trying to use it in a query like this:

```
SELECT `club_name`,`city` FROM `table` WHERE `public_gig` = 'y' AND `zip` IN (@zips)
#I also tried syntax "IN ("@zips"), IN @zips and IN ('@zips')"
```

But, I cannot get it to work. (I am using placeholders and such as you see in my link above.)

I was able to get this to work:

```
$fzip=shift(@Zips);
$lzip=pop(@Zips);
SELECT `club_name`,`city` FROM `table` WHERE `public_gig` = 'y' AND `zip` BETWEEN $fzip AND $lzip

    ZIP | public_gig | start_time | fin_time | city       | club_name | and so on
  33416 | y          | 9pm        | 2am      | clearwater | beach bar | yada
```

But, for obvious reasons and some resemblance of accuracy, that is not really what I want. Just wanted to see if I could get SOMETHING working on my own.

Why can't I get the query to work with the zips in the array using IN?? Nothing is returned and there is no error.

There is actually a lot more in that query but, I left it all out to keep it short here.

I tried to figure it out by myself. Obviously, my learning capacity for the day is near peak.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10):

All of the examples posted here will screw up if any of your values contain single-quotes, don't use them.

Instead (assuming `$dbh` is the database handle for your mysql connection):

```
my $zip_string = join q{,}, map $dbh->quote($_), @zips;
```

and interpolate *that*.

Or, for something nice, but not half as outlandish as DBIx::Perlish: [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SQL::Abstract).

```
my $sqla = SQL::Abstract->new;
my ($sql, @bind) = $sqla->select(
  'table', 
  ['club_name', 'city'],
  {
    public_gig => y',
    zip => { -in => \@zips },
  }
);

$dbh->prepare($sql);
$dbh->execute(@bind);
# fetchrow etc.
```

Comment: Leaving aside the "crack-fueled" part, the statement about "all of the examples" and single quotes is factually incorrect.  :-)

Comment: Thank you. I do sterilize quite well and am using DBI amd placeholders but, your advice is taken quite seriously by me. I will continue to strive for better security. I will look into SQL::Abstract and see if I need to / am capable of convert(ing) my current queries. I will prob post another question with a working example of what I finally came up with. Thanks!

Comment: @Stephayne point is that constructing the `in` this way *doesn't* use placeholders, so you need to use proper quoting.

Answer (score 8):

This **can** be done using placeholders, you just have to work around the limitation that each placeholder can only accept a single value.  `WHERE zip IN (?)` won't work because you're (presumably) looking for more than one value (otherwise, why use `IN`?).

You can, however, easily build a statement on the fly with the correct number of placeholders:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @zips = (12345, 54321, 90210);
my $stmt = "SELECT `club_name`,`city`
            FROM `table`
            WHERE `public_gig` = 'y' AND `zip` IN ("
           . join(', ', ('?') x @zips) . ')';

print "$stmt\n";

# Now just:
# my $sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
# $sth->execute(@zips);
```

Comment: This is very true -- it can become somewhat confusing if you're using it in a statement with more placeholders/bind values, but this works just great. And if it gets too complicated that's where something like SQLA will really help.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't mind using weird CPAN modules,
with [`DBIx::Perlish`](http://search.cpan.org/~gruber/DBIx-Perlish/) you can just say:

```
my @results = db_fetch {
   my $t: table;
   $t->public_gig eq "y";
   $t->zip  <-  @zips;
};
```

and it will do the right thing.

*Full disclosure*: I am the author of `DBIx::Perlish`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know perl too much, but this looks like a simple SQL problem: why don't you just build the SQL IN clause from your array? You should get something like

> AND zip IN ('zip 1', 'zip 2', '...')

I doubt just adding an array in perl will create the right strings for the SQL string ...

Answer (score -6):

You need to turn the array into a string of values seperated by commas.
Try this :

```
my $zipcodes = join('\',\'',@zips);
SELECT `club_name`,`city` FROM `table` WHERE `public_gig` = 'y' AND `zip` IN ('".$zipcodes."');
```

Comment: Thank you @Sam Broad! Worked perfectly! Taking the extra time to use my vars really helped me out.

Comment: -1 any teaching code for DBI without placeholders makes Bobby Tables weep.

Comment: Snarky comments without pointers to docs explaining what you mean makes teachers weep.